# Geting null pointer exception while trying to do Datasource JNDI lookup in tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I tried to do establish a database connection through DatabaseSource JNDI look up.I followed the instruction in Tomcat website and did as below

I added the resource to  server.xml

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/myDB" auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"/> 
<ResourceParams name="jdbc/myDB">
  <parameter>
    <name>factory</name>
    <value>org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>driverClassName</name>
    <value>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>url</name>
    <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@111.111.111.111:1234:DBNME</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>username</name>
    <value>Dobby</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>password</name>
    <value>pwd</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>maxActive</name>
    <value>20</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>maxIdle</name>
    <value>10</value>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <name>maxWait</name>
    <value>-1</value>
  </parameter>
</ResourceParams>
```

web.xml

```
 <resource-ref>
    <description>MY DataBase</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/myDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

In code

```
Context initContext = new  InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB");
            Connection con =  ds.getConnection();
```

I am getting this error

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1452)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.sample.XML.doGet(XML.java:39)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    ... 21 more
```

I have OJDBC14.jar in my tomcat lib.

I found the same question in stackoverflow but the solutions provided there is not working for me.Thats why I am posting it again.

Comment: Can you check a confusion - jdbc/mydb in resource ref and Datasource as GMEDB?

Comment: Sorry its by mistake.previously I tried using myDB   only.Still got the error

Comment: Why do you put a pic of your code? please add your code, its easier to help you that way :)

Comment: have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDB" );
```

As you resource name states `jdbc/myDB`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting the xml

```
   <resource-ref>     
    <description>     
     </description>     
    <res-ref-name></res-ref-name>     
    <res-type></res-type>     
    <res-auth></res-auth>     
  </resource-ref>
```

tag in tomcat Server.xml and by restarting server and see whether that solves your problem or not?

Comment: No I am getting the same exception again